# Not allowing characters after Space. Mysql Insert With PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

Ok so I think this is easy but I dont know (I'm a novice to PHP and MySQL).

I have a select that is getting data from a table in the database. I am simply taking whatever options the user selects and putting it into a separate table with a php mysql insert statement.

But I am having a problem. When I hit submit, everything is submitted properly except for any select options that have spaces don't submit after the first space. For example if the option was `COMPUTER REPAIR`, all that would get sent is COMPUTER. I will post code if needed, and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Ok here is my select code:

```
<?php
  include("./config.php");
  $query="SELECT id,name FROM category_names ORDER BY name";
  $result = mysql_query ($query);
  echo"<div style='overflow:auto;width:100%'><label>Categories (Pick three that describe your business)</label><br/><select name='select1'><option value='0'>Please Select A Category</option>";
  // printing the list box select command
  while($catinfo=mysql_fetch_array($result)){//Array or records stored in $nt


  echo "<option>$catinfo[name]</option><br/>

 ";

  }

echo"</select></div>";

  ?>
```

And here is my insert code ( Just to let you know its got everything not just the select!)

```
?php
    require("./config.php");
    $companyname = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes(trim($_REQUEST['name'])));
    $phone = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['phone']));
    $zipcode = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['zipcode']));
    $city = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['city']));
    $description = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['description']));
    $website = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['website']));
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['address']));
    $other = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['other']));
    $payment = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['payment']));
    $products = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['products']));
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['email']));
    $select1 = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['select1']));
    $select2 = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['select2']));
    $select3 = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['select3']));
    $save=$_POST['save'];
    if(!empty($save)){

    $sql="INSERT INTO gj (name, phone, city, zipcode, description, dateadded, website, address1, other2, payment_options, Products, email,cat1,cat2,cat3)
    VALUES
    ('$companyname','$phone','$city','$zipcode','$description',curdate(),'$website','$address','$other','$payment','$products','$email','$select1','$select2','$select3')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$link))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "<br/><h2><font color='green' style='font-size:15px'>1 business         added</font></h2>";

    mysql_close($link);
}

    ?>
```

Comment: It would definitely help if you could post the relevant portions of your code.

Comment: i posted some code...I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the `value="$catinfo[name]"` on your `<option>` tags so they look like this:

```
echo "<option value=\"".htmlspecialchars($catinfo['name'])."\">".$catinfo['name']."</option>";
```

Since you've omitted them, it's using whatever is in between the `<option>` tags by default and since there is no quotes around them, it determines the space as being the end of the value. By placing the actual value you want inserted into the database within the `value` attribute, you're distinctly telling it to use the full phrase between the quotes.

Also, remove the `<br/>` as you don't need to place breaks within a `<select>` element.

Comment: echo "<option value="{$catinfo[name]}">$catinfo[name]</option><br/>";

Comment: don't forget `htmlspecialchars` !;)

Comment: I keep getting an error... is this right? while($catinfo=mysql_fetch_array($result)){//Array or records stored in $catinfo


      echo "<option value="$cat_info[name]"></option><br/>

Comment: Ok I feel really stupid...Im still getting an error saying       "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /Users/Jacob/Sites/gjpages/addbusiness.php on line 42"??

Comment: Try the code posted in the answer above. And make sure you didn't write `";` twice

Comment: agh, don't access array keys as constants, it's `$catinfo['name']`, *not* `$catinfo[name]`; the latter is abusive and sometimes dangerous.

Comment: @Jake Refresh the page, I had made changes to the code to add `htmlspecialchars` as suggested by meze.  @meze Why would he replace any `'`?  @Mark E I agree; I was only mimicking his original code. I've updated my example to be semantically correct.

Comment: @mririgo Now it's fine, you had ' instead of " (you changed that)

Comment: Thanks Everyone! @mririgo your code worked perfectly the second time

Comment: @Mark E: although I upvoted your comment, I'd have to retract it if I could. The key is not considered a constant in this case, since it is being evaluated in a double-quoted string. If I'm correct a constant will only be evaluated as such in a double-quoted string like so: echo "the following is a ${constant}". (Although one would usually use UPPERCASE letters to distinguish constants, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: @fireeyedboy: the code in the answer was previously: `echo "<option value=\"".htmlspecialchars($catinfo[name])."\">".$catinfo[name]."</option>";` -- which agrees with what I stated.  Inside double quoted strings it's my preference to use, say `"{$catinfo['name']}"` over, say, `"$catinfo[name]"` as it prevents a poor copy and paste from breaking something.

Comment: @Mark E: Ah, I see, I wasn't aware of that. In that case I refrain from wanting to retract my upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a common mistake that people encounter. In order to access the data stored in Database as it is Kindly follow the following format:

```
echo "<option>'".$catinfo[name]."'</option><br/>";
```

if you want value to stored in option use the following format:

```
echo "<option value='".$catinfo[name]."'>'".$catinfo[name]."'</option><br/>";
```

It will display data from database as it is. 
I hope it helps!